# Import data from Two open workbooks with variable names

Tags: vba, excel

I´m trying to activate, process data and import information from two different open workbooks(BCH mm-yy.xlsx and Portafolio mm-yy.xlsx), where mm-yy changes every month.

As an example of how to activate both workbooks i did the following:

```
Sub ActivateWorkbook()

    FName1 = Dir("c:\BCH" & "??-??" & ".xlsx")
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OK"

    FName2 = Dir("c:\Portafolio" & "??-??" & ".xlsx")
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OK"

End Sub
```

The problem is that when I run the macro it doesn´t identify which workbook I am refering to and it performs the tasks (write OK as an example) in just one of the workbooks. That is, it writes "OK" in cells A3 and A5 in BCH workbook when it should write "OK" in A5 from BCH and A3 of Portfolio. Any advice on how to solve it?

Comment: If the workbooks are already open, then why use Dir()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any advice on how to solve it?

Of course. This kind of random patterns is well-knowingly due to the use of unqualified ranges and worksheet objects. when you refer to an unqualified range, it automatically refers to the `ActiveSheet` whatever it happens to be at run time.

The solution is to use full qualification of your objects. You can do so by holding an explicit reference to any workbook you open, and by specifying the worksheet that holds your range.

```
FName1 = Dir("c:\BCH" & "??-??" & ".xlsx")
Dim wb1 as workbook, ws1 as worksheet
Set wb1 = Workbooks.open(FName1)
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")    ' <-- This is a fully qualified Worksheet
ws1.Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "whatever" ' <-- This is a fully qualified range

' And similarly with FName2...
```

Comment: It appears 1004 error  when implementing it. Do I need to perform any further change?

Comment: @MaríaPilarAlcalde yes indeed, you need to change the strings to what actually corresponds to your data, file names and worksheet names :)

Comment: @MaríaPilarAlcalde did you get through this?

Comment: @MaríaPilarAlcalde https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235